# JQuery sum rows with unique id elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to display the sum of all the input elements (quantity and amount) respectively in the last 2 cells of each line.
Every element in this table has a unique id. Each input element has an id that contains information about the row it appears in :

```js
var trRows = ['tr2', 'tr3', 'tr4', 'tr5', 'tr6', 'tr7', 'tr8', 'tr9', 'tr10', 'tr11', 'tr12'];

trRows.forEach(function(trRow) {

  var $sumQuantity = 0;
  var $sumAmount = 0;

  $(this).find('#tr' + trRow + 'input[id *= "qty"]').each(function() {

    $sumQuantity += +$(this).text() || 0;
  });

  $(this).find('#tr' + trRow + 'input[id *= "amount"]').each(function() {

    $sumAmount += +$(this).text() || 0;
  });

  $('#sumQtyTR' + trRows, this).html($sumQuantity);
  $('#sumAmountTR' + trRows, this).html($sumAmount);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

  <tr id='tr2'>
    <td id='td2_65'><span id='span_i2qty_65'><input id='input_i2qty_65' class='editbox'></span>
    </td>
    <td id='td2_65'><span id='span_i2amount_65'><input id='input_i2amount_65' class='editbox'></span>
    </td>

    <td id='td2_66'><span id='span_i2qty_66'><input id='input_i2qty_66' class='editbox'></span>
    </td>
    <td id='td2_66'><span id='span_i2amount_66'><input id='input_i2amount_66' class='editbox'></span>
    </td>

    <td id='sumQtyTR2'></td>
    <td id='sumAmountTR2'></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id='tr3'>
    <td id='td3_65'><span id='span_i3qty_65'><input id='input_i3qty_65' class='editbox'></span>
    </td>
    <td id='td3_65'><span id='span_i3amount_65'><input id='input_i3amount_65' class='editbox'></span>
    </td>

    <td id='td3_66'><span id='span_i3qty_66'><input id='input_i3qty_66' class='editbox'></span>
    </td>
    <td id='td3_66'><span id='span_i3amount_66'><input id='input_i3amount_66' class='editbox'></span>
    </td>

    <td id='sumQtyTR3'></td>
    <td id='sumAmountTR3'></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- More rows -->

</table>
```

I can't figure out why sums are not displayed. Selectors ? Thanks

Comment: `'#tr'+trRow input[id*="qty"]'` quotes are mismatched. the tr id is incorrect.

Comment: Hi @dexter-vegas I haven't taken the opportunity to read your question, before I do, I thought I should first mention that IDs are intended to be unique.  If you find you have used an ID in an HTML document more than once, you may have done something wrong.  Your `td` elements either should be using a `class` in place of the `id` or the ID's value should be made more unique (e.g., `td2_65_qty` and `td2_65_amt`)

Comment: This whole approach is overall just confusing. If your inputs had an additional class that you can filter by, it would be simple to iterate over the table rows and sum the inputs by class. No id needed at all. Dom elements, particularly ones in a table, already have a unique identifier you can use: it's index within the table, and the cells within each row. But i don't think you even need that.

Comment: Just as a constructive comment. We are in the ES6+ era. We don't use `var` anymore. We use `let` and `const` https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75

Comment: @PatricioVargas eh, probably bad advice to just blindly advise against using something in favor of using something else, when that something else isn't supported by browsers that are still very much in use today without making that fact clear. That advice is more likely to cause more problems due to not understanding how to properly use let/const. That advice simply doesn't belong here.

Comment: `$('#sumQtyTR'+trRows, this)` but `trRows` is an `Array` object.

Comment: Despite logical issues, you had several HTML (non-terminated tags) and JavaScript (missing single quotes); which I took the liberty in editing (pending peer-review since my rating is low).  Hope you don't mind

Comment: @Kevin all the cool kidzzz use it. The JS gurus that invente all those awesome things that everyone uses. It's not require but it is best practice :) http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-let

Comment: @Mike You are right. Ids are unique by definition. My title should have been "JQuery sum rows without classes" since I can only rely on Ids to identify the data carried by the input elements which already have the class "editbox".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Recommendations

Within your code there are a few points of interest that may be worth consideration to reduce the clutter:

1. IDs are intended to be unique.  There should never be a time where an ID is used in more than one place in an HTML document.  In places where you think two or more elements might share an `id`, you should use a `class` instead
2. Unless you are using jQuery elsewhere, you should know that jQuery is not necessary.  It does provide several advantages (including cross-browser compliance), but you should consider using native JavaScript and a packager that will add the necessary polyfills

---

### Examples

The examples below are intended to be close in structure/design to the original source code in the OP for learning purposes; however, it should be noted that there are many ways to optimize to improve performance and readability.

One major point worth mentioning is in the logic flow.  The structure in these examples are inefficient, since every time an input is updated it is looping over and recalculating sums for all of the rows.  This could be improved by only calculating and updating the sum of the altered row.  Additionally, holding an array of interested rows (e.g., `row_ids`) could be better improved with more semantic HTML and the use of classes (if needing to be selective).

There are some other major changes made to both the jQuery and ES6+ example below.  Most notably is the onChange event handler.  The code in the OP iterated over each ID immediately on page load, but never again.  There needed to be a hook into some event that would be called when the input box was modified; thus the onChange or onBlur event is necessary in order to re-calculate the values.

#### jQuery Example

Given these two recommendations, I've made some substantial changes to your HTML and JavaScript, which include but are not limited to:

- removed unnecessary IDs and added respective classes
- use reduce for sum calculation

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  let row_ids = ['tr2', 'tr3', 'tr4', 'tr5', 'tr6', 'tr7', 'tr8', 'tr9', 'tr10', 'tr11', 'tr12'];

  function changeEventHandler() {
    $.each(row_ids, function(ndx, row_id) {

      const $row = $('#' + row_id)
      if (!$row.length)
        return;

      const quantity = $row.find('input.quantity').get().reduce(function(acc, input) {
        acc += parseFloat(input.value) || 0;
        return acc
      }, 0)
      const amount = $row.find('input.amount').get().reduce(function(acc, input) {
        acc += parseFloat(input.value) || 0;
        return acc
      }, 0)

      $row.find('.sum.quantity').text(quantity)
      $row.find('.sum.amount').text(amount)

    });
  }

  $(document).on('change', 'input', changeEventHandler)
})
```

```css
.sum { background: #eee; }
th,td {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}
table { width: 100%; }
input { width: 40%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Fill in each input with a number (watch sums auto-update):
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>QTY 1</th>
      <th>AMT 1</th>
      <th>QTY 2</th>
      <th>AMT 2</th>
      <th>SUM QTY</th>
      <th>SUM AMT</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id='tr2'>
      <!-- td: use class and not id -->
      <!-- remove unnecessary classes -->
      <td class="item_65"><span><input class='quantity'></span></td>
      <td class="item_65"><span><input class='amount'></span></td>
      <td class="item_66"><span><input class='quantity'></span></td>
      <td class="item_66"><span><input class='amount'></span></td>

      <td class="sum quantity"></td>
      <td class="sum amount"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id='tr3'>
      <td class="item_65"><span><input class='quantity'></span></td>
      <td class="item_65"><span><input class='amount'></span></td>
      <td class="item_66"><span><input class='quantity'></span></td>
      <td class="item_66"><span><input class='amount'></span></td>

      <td class="sum quantity"></td>
      <td class="sum amount"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- More rows -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

#### ES6+ Example

Given the two recommendations, I've made some substantial changes to your HTML and JavaScript, which include but are not limited to:

- removed unnecessary IDs and added respective classes
- removed unnecessary jQuery code (used native event handling)
- use `reduce` for sum calculation
- use arrow functions for simplified syntax

Note: as mentioned prior, the code may not work in all browsers (all versions and variations), but should work in most of the newer browsers.  The snippet will work in most (if not all) because it is configured to use babel

```js
function changeEventHandler() {
  let row_ids = ['tr2', 'tr3', 'tr4', 'tr5', 'tr6', 'tr7', 'tr8', 'tr9', 'tr10', 'tr11', 'tr12'];
  // could iterate over the rows:
  //   document.querySelectorAll(selector) 
  //   where selector is 'tr' or '[id^="tr"]' 

  row_ids.forEach(row_id => {
    const row = document.querySelector(`#${row_id}`)
    if (row == null)
      return;

    const qty_el = row.querySelectorAll('input.quantity')
    const quantity = [...qty_el].reduce((acc, cv) => acc += parseFloat(cv.value) || 0, 0)
    const amt_el = row.querySelectorAll('input.amount')
    const amount = [...amt_el].reduce((acc, cv) => acc += parseFloat(cv.value) || 0, 0)

    row.querySelector('.sum.quantity').textContent = quantity
    row.querySelector('.sum.amount').textContent = amount

  });
}

window.setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(() => this.onchange = changeEventHandler)
},0);
```

```css
.sum { background: #eee; }
th,td {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}
table { width: 100%; }
input { width: 40%; }
```

```html
Fill in each input with a number (watch sums auto-update):
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>QTY 1</th>
      <th>AMT 1</th>
      <th>QTY 2</th>
      <th>AMT 2</th>
      <th>SUM QTY</th>
      <th>SUM AMT</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id='tr2'>
      <!-- td: use class and not id -->
      <!-- remove unnecessary classes -->
      <td class="item_65"><span><input class='quantity'></span></td>
      <td class="item_65"><span><input class='amount'></span></td>
      <td class="item_66"><span><input class='quantity'></span></td>
      <td class="item_66"><span><input class='amount'></span></td>

      <td class="sum quantity"></td>
      <td class="sum amount"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id='tr3'>
      <td class="item_65"><span><input class='quantity'></span></td>
      <td class="item_65"><span><input class='amount'></span></td>
      <td class="item_66"><span><input class='quantity'></span></td>
      <td class="item_66"><span><input class='amount'></span></td>

      <td class="sum quantity"></td>
      <td class="sum amount"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- More rows -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: May be jQuery is not needed, but it's wanted by the OP.

Comment: @PoulBak Thanks for that input.  I consider it speculative to arrive at any conclusions for what the OP *wants*.  The OP has not expressed desire for one over the other (they have yet to return for comment).  It's not uncommon for new programmers to first be introduced to jQuery.  Without their feedback, I took the opportunity to explore the non-jQuery realm.  I've also made substantial other changes to the code; although, there is plenty of room to improve it further.  That said, I will update to include a jQuery response -- thank you

Comment: @Mike Thank you for that extensive answer / solution. In an effort to make my question concise I omitted to mention that :
- I am using JQuery. Why? Initially my understanding was that in order to send data to server side script I needed JQuery's Ajax. Now am learning that it can be done with the XMLHttpRequest object in native Javascript.
- The reason behind putting an id to all the elements in the table was to be able to identify the data once it was sent to the server side script then off to a database.

Comment: @Mike So I left ids to the elements but I replaced the "editbox" with "quantity" and "amount" respectively and made the changes to existing JS / CSS. I added your JS code and the only thing I changed was the event onchange to onclick since onchange was only updating after the second change.

A lot to chew for me. Thanks so much Mike.

Comment: @DexterVegas Your question was tagged with jQuery, but just because something is used does not mean that it is required.  jQuery is JavaScript.  It's a library that sits on top of JavaScript so if it's possible to do in jQuery, there is a native solution.  Because it's an independent library, it means it has it's own syntax and way of doing things, so new entrants to the language learn the jQuery-way and not necessarily the underlying JavaScript way.

Comment: @DexterVegas I don't mean to compare/contrast jQuery vs VanillaJS, but jQuery offers a host of features at a cost (overhead/performance).  Most notably it provides a reduction in code to perform operations like event handling and/or AJAX requests.  IMO, the biggest usecase for it is its cross-browser compliance.  As JavaScript is involving, it's introduced functions like `querySelector`, which makes finding elements easier -- what was once a jQuery/Prototype key feature is now trivial.

Comment: @DexterVegas If you want a simpler native way of performing AJAX, consider the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).  Again, cross-browser compliance should always be kept in mind, but for that, in place of jQuery I would recommend using something like Babel to perform your polyfills.  Regarding the code above, still ensure that your IDs are unique (non-repetitive).